# Celery ignoring config for serializer?

Tags: python, celery, pickle

I have a Celery app (4.4.6) that uses dataclasses. Since JSON can't serialize/deserialize dataclasses, I have forced the use of pickle throughout (I'm aware of the risk, but I think it's mitigated in the way the app is deployed). *However*, I am getting errors from within the app from kombu, saying `TypeError: Object of type ResourceGroup is not JSON serializable`. Everything else is working, so in general, it has to be using pickle OK, but in this one case it isn't. However nothing in the stacktrace that comes with the exception mentions my code. The structure of the software is tasks that create other tasks dynamically as they perform discovery, using `delay()`. Almost all the tasks are passed this ResourceGroup object, and they are *running fine*, except one (I think, judging by the frequency of these errors, and the logging I am getting for completing tasks).

This is how I'm configuring Celery in my worker. Is there some other setting I need to set to *really really* make it use pickle in all situations? (alternatively, is there a JSON serializer/deserializer that can reconstitute dataclasses?)

```
class CeleryConfig:
    task_serializer = 'pickle'
    result_serializer = 'pickle'
    event_serializer = 'pickle'
    accept_content = ['pickle']
    result_accept_content = ['pickle']


app = Celery('collector',
             backend='redis://' + Config.REDIS_HOST,
             broker='redis://' + Config.REDIS_HOST,
             include=['tasks'])
app.config_from_object(CeleryConfig)
```

Update:

Here's a full example of one of the exceptions:

```
[2020-07-23 05:02:10,621: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method active() [reply_to:{'exchange': 'reply.celery.pidbox', 'routing_key': 'cde2e89b-bb81-3c19-8491-b57b072e5f29'} ticket:6c2cc493-0e2d-4a85-821b-350bdc4bceeb]
[2020-07-23 05:02:10,621: ERROR/MainProcess] Control command error: EncodeError(TypeError('Object of type ResourceGroup is not JSON serializable'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 50, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 221, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 69, in dumps
    return _dumps(s, cls=cls or _default_encoder,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 59, in default
    return super(JSONEncoder, self).default(o)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type ResourceGroup is not JSON serializable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/pidbox.py", line 46, in on_message
    self.node.handle_message(body, message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 145, in handle_message
    return self.dispatch(**body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 112, in dispatch
    self.reply({self.hostname: reply},
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 149, in reply
    self.mailbox._publish_reply(data, exchange, routing_key, ticket,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 280, in _publish_reply
    producer.publish(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 167, in publish
    body, content_type, content_encoding = self._prepare(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 252, in _prepare
    body) = dumps(body, serializer=serializer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 221, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 54, in _reraise_errors
    reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vine/five.py", line 194, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 50, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 221, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 69, in dumps
    return _dumps(s, cls=cls or _default_encoder,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 59, in default
    return super(JSONEncoder, self).default(o)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type ResourceGroup is not JSON serializable
```

I agree that ResourceGroup isn't JSON serializable. I just don't understand why it's trying! :-)

update2:

I got the celery worker running with concurrency=1 in the debugger, and now with a breakpoint in the JSON serializer (which I should never hit) I get a stop. From reading back inside kombu, the first mention of serializer in the stack trace seems to be from Node.reply() in pidbox.py where self.mailbox.serializer is None (and defaults to JSON because of that). I don't see where that Mailbox object is originally created though.

update3:

The Control object appears to always create a Mailbox that will accept and send JSON, regardless of any config:

```
    """Worker remote control client."""

    Mailbox = Mailbox

    def __init__(self, app=None):
        self.app = app
        self.mailbox = self.Mailbox(
            app.conf.control_exchange,
            type='fanout',
            accept=['json'],
            producer_pool=lazy(lambda: self.app.amqp.producer_pool),
            queue_ttl=app.conf.control_queue_ttl,
            reply_queue_ttl=app.conf.control_queue_ttl,
            queue_expires=app.conf.control_queue_expires,
            reply_queue_expires=app.conf.control_queue_expires,
        )
```

Comment: Do you get the error in the worker log, or from your producer (application that sends tasks to the Celery cluster)?

Comment: In the worker log, although from MainProcess, not the actual Worker processes (it's prefork).

Comment: Can you try to run this:

`app.conf.update(task_serializer='pickle', accept_content=['pickle'], result_serializer='pickle')`

to ensure the config is set correctly?

Comment: @JonasDrotleff no, no difference there.

Comment: Looks like an issue with Celery/kombu for me. If the JSON Serrializer is hard-coded there is probably no way around that.

Comment: Agreed - started up a query on the celery mailing list.

Comment: Ehi @AnotherHwdie I'm getting the same error on Celery 4.4.6 and it seems to have become more disruptive in 4.4.7 :( Did you find any workaround? Is there an official issue/thread to follow?

Comment: @rickyalbert Here's my report. I rolled back a bunch of code to before I started using dataclasses in the end. https://groups.google.com/g/celery-users/c/LKXvgPslH6k

Comment: Any news about this issue 1 year later? I'm trying to fix the same problem (Celery 4.4.7).

Comment: @IsraelFonseca yes, actually! I got a github notification for a PR that is supposed to fix this, just a couple of weeks ago. I don't know how long that takes to make it into a release for Celery... I ended up rolling back my dataclasses code, last year :-(

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6672

Comment: @AnotherHowie, interesting! I'll follow that issue too. Thanks for the info.